# Need to fetch table cell data without id or class using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to fetch table cell data,where the cell data is containing information that could be done using the language either javascript or jquery.that data i need to insert into mydatabase ex. mysql.

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: Where is your HTML Code?

Comment: You should post your HTML too.. That way it becomes helpful to correct someone.. Still I have posted an answer that might help

Answer (score 0):

Tested script:
At the end table cell data is displayed using a simple Alert

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    //gets table
    var oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

      //gets cells of current row  
       var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

       //gets amount of cells of current row
       var cellLength = oCells.length;

       //loops through each cell in current row
       for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){

              // get your cell info here

              var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
              alert(cellVal);
              // Here you can send your data using Ajax to your php page for your storage.
           }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
<table id="tableid">
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$("#tableid tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find("td").each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4t7sLk4/)**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would want to get data or values from an HTML table which are no `id` or `class` name assigned.

Let's say this is a demo code :

```html
<tbody>
     <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Order is received</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Parcel drop off at bbbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Parcel has been collected at cccc</td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

My approach usually I will try it in my browser's terminal with this method:

```js
$('${name_of_the_selector}').each(function(i, item) {
    console.log(item.innerText)
});
```

To get the selector, you can get it from the `Inspector` as the following screenshot:

[image]

And replace the `highlighted` code with the `selector` you just copied.

[image]
Hit Enter and you will get something like this:

[image]

For `insert` data into your database, `return` the value and customise your logic or the function there.